# Install nasm on GitHub Windows job

Tags: windows, nasm, github-actions

I am building OpenSSL for Windows using a GitHub workflow. Because OpenSSL needs NASM, I tried installing it like this, using Chocolatey:

```
- name: install packages
  run: choco install nasm
- name: configure
  run: |
    refreshenv
    cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" [...]
```

The thing is that `choco install nasm` does not seem to put it in the PATH. I tried to add `refeshenv` in my configure step, but it does not do it either.

How can I put NASM in the PATH for a github job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed with the following:

```
- name: install packages
  run: |
    choco install nasm
    echo "C:\Program Files\NASM" | Out-File -FilePath $env:GITHUB_PATH -Encoding utf8 -Append
- name: configure
  run: cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" [...]
```

Which seems to be the Windows way to extend the PATH, similar to [the documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#adding-a-system-path) (which is for Unix at this time).